# Однородные сказуемые?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая пред И?

> Продолжай развиваться(,) и еще не раз удивишь себя саму.

Благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая в сложносочинённом предложении необходима. Оба простых предложения односоставные, но первое предложение побудительное, второе повествовательное.

***Продолжай развиваться, и еще не раз удивишь себя саму.***

Мне больше нравится вариант с ТИРЕ, так как вторая часть имеет значение следствия:

***Продолжай развиваться - и еще не раз удивишь себя саму.***